# Best way to resolve conflict between feature and test branch but without affect the main?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Let's say you have 3 branches:

- feature => branch you add the implementation
- test => other developers merge their implementations to test branch to test it
- main => main branch, implementation that goes live

> Ideally, test should be equal to master

Now, let's say your feature branch conflicts with test branch (test branch includes changes which has not been added to main). However, you can't run the command `git merge test` because in that case you will add unverified changes to your feature branch.

What is the best practice to solve that problem?

My solution:

```bash
git checkout -b feature-test feature

# merge changes from test into feature-test
git merge test

# merge feature-test into test, test your implementation 
# then release your feature branch and merge it into the main
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be fine.

Comment: I don’t see the problem. `test` seems like an integration branch, specifically a throwaway branch where multiple features are tested before each of the branches are merged into `main`. If `test` is an integration branch then you want all of these features to intermingle, which means that you want to merge as per usual including resolving merge conflicts.

Comment: I do not see that you touch `feature` after you create `feature-test`. What is the point of creating `feature-test` then?

Comment: the main problem is that test branch is also protected, i can not checkout the test branch then run the git merge feature command

Comment: My point is that you you are creating `feature-test` and doing stuff with it and in your recipe you do not touch `feature` again.... so, **unless you want to keep `feature` there on purpose (for whatever practical reason you might have)**, you would get the same results if you avoided creating `feature-test` and worked those steps on `feature` instead.

Comment: feature is the branch in which will be merged into main. if I run the "git merge test" into feature branch, then when I merge my changes into main, i will also add un-verified changes(from other developers) to main

Comment: Ok, then the new branch makes sense. But it seems like protecting `test` is causing unnecessary workflow issues.

Comment: Since the merge commit that you are going to make is temporary anyway (for your own integration test), you can also `git checkout --detach`, provided that you are confortable with operating in detached HEAD mode.